# Remove special characters from filenames

Tags: plugins, images, database, uploads

I have a website that i transfered recently from one host to another. Unfortunately when i did that, i noticed that all the images that had special characters in it lik (é, è, à, ...) weren't showing anymore in my pages.

I'm trying to resolve to this issue. I'm thinking maybe if i can rename these imagaes by removing/replacing the special characters in them i can solve this problem.

So my question if anyone of you knows a plugin that changes the names of the "upload" files and in the database aswell that would be much helpful.

Thank you in advance

Comment: It's worth asking the new host if they can help. It sounds like character encoding might be set differently on the new server, and a setting might just fix the issue without having to rename everything.

Comment: Thanks i checked with them but there was nothing wrong with the encoding in mysql. But i solved my issue with this plugin: Media File Renamer